# Different durations for SKAction - skipping around after action completion?

Tags: swift

I have the following code in a pong paddle game in the `GameViewController`:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        main.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x,duration: 4), completion: {
           print( "COMPLETED TOUCH BEGAN")
        })
    }
}
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        main.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x,duration: 1), completion: {
            print( "COMPLETED TOUCH MOVED")
        })
    }
}
```

For some reason, when the duration of `touchesBegan` is greater than the duration of `touchesMoved`, my player will complete the `touchesMoved` actions first (even though `touchesBegan` had to come first), and then jump to a different x-position and then move with duration 4 to complete the `touchesBegan`. It's almost like the player reaches the position designated in `touchesMoved` (which should be almost exactly identical to the position in `touchesBegan`), goes back a somewhat arbitrary amount, and then moves to `touchesBegan` position. Is there a reason why it's jumping back and then moving like so?

My hypothesis is that for some reason, the `touchesMoved` actions are ran concurrently, and when they finish, the position jumps back to where it is slowly moving in `touchesBegan` and completes that movement to completion - almost like there are two objects moving at different rates with the slower one coming up after the faster one finishes. Is this at all correct? If so, why is it like this?

**Edit**:

I see that when I make the paddle move to one side of the screen, then tap on the opposite end of the screen and slide over, it will move to the final position that I released at, and then jump and move to where I first pressed. It's almost like the first action is playing in the background. The strange thing is if I hold my finger down (keeping the `touchesMoved` method called) until the movement in the `touchesBegan` finishes (so here it's 4 seconds), it doesn't jump to the other side of the screen!

In summary, I have multiple SKActions running with different durations, and from my observation, the priority is over the most recent action added to the action array. But instead of playing multiple actions over each other, the object jumps to different places on the screen to complete the final action.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You are creating many conflicting actions in a very short period of time.

Comment: @nathan I was actually following along with [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/LdL99CH23E8?t=15m8s) and figured that what he was doing is normal. I'm completely new to SpriteKit. Either way, I'm curious now as to what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set up a second `SKAction` moving the same node, the second one doesn't cancel out the first. Rather, the position of the node is calculated after every frame based on all `SKAction`s running. If the `SKAction`s have the same duration and run at the same time, the last `SKAction` to run will always win out. For example:

```
// Same duration, node finishes at 100
main.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: -100, duration: 2)) //first to run
main.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: 100, duration: 2))  //second to run
```

If the first `SKAction` has a greater duration however, after the second `SKAction` has finished the position will only be calculated based on the first `SKAction`, for example:

```
//First SKAction's duration is longer, node finishes at -100
main.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: -100, duration: 3))
main.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: 100, duration: 2))
```

That's the reason why you're seeing the 'jump'.

[SKAction documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction):

> A node can run multiple actions simultaneously, even if those actions
>   were executed at different times. The scene keeps track of how far
>   each action is from completing and computes the effect that the action
>   has on the node. For example, if you run two actions that move the
>   same node, both actions apply changes to every frame. If the move
>   actions were in equal and opposite directions, the node would remain
>   stationary.

In your code `touchesMoved` can be called many times, and each time it is adding another SKAction to the node. I recommend you remove all actions on the main node before running another SKAction:

```
main.removeAllActions()
```

So in the end it will be:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        main.removeAllActions()
        main.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x,duration: 4), completion: {
            print( "COMPLETED TOUCH BEGAN")
        })
    }
}
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        main.removeAllActions()
        main.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x,duration: 1), completion: {
            print( "COMPLETED TOUCH MOVED")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Craig! I'll reread this again when I have access to Xcode but I am a bit confused on what you mean by the actions not cancelling out despite Apple's documentation saying what I think is the opposite. If the moves are equal but opposite, the docs say the actions will cancel. But you are saying that the last skaction will win out. Could you please clarify this? Thanks again for the detailed answer.

Comment: Ah sorry, it is a bit confusing - it appears as though `moveTo` and `moveBy` work differently, and the docs appear to be referring to `moveBy`. Let's say one moveBy specifies an `x` movement of 100, and another specifies an `x` movement of -100 - since 100 minus 100 is equal to 0, the two calls would cancel eachother out. (assuming their easing was identical)

Comment: thank you for clarifying! So with my jump, the touchesBegan is first and runs on a "phantom" in the background while the touchesMoved actions run with the shorter duration? And then once the touchesMoved actions end, it jumps to the phantom object's position? I'm a bit confused on why exactly it's functioning this way and why the moveTo command works this way.

Comment: I don't think it's a "phantom", rather it's being overrided immediately afterwards by another SKAction prior to being rendered. `moveTo` "animates from its current position to its new position." To illustrate imagine a hypothetical: node is at x=0, we set up two moveTo `SKAction`s, both have linear easing, with duration of exactly 10 frames - `SKAction` 1 moveTo x=100, SKAction 2 moveTo x=-100. So in frame 1 it would do the following: `SKAction` 1, moveTo (0 + (100/10)) = 10. But now for `SKAction` 2, moveTo (0 + (-100/10)) = -10. Now render the node at -10.

Comment: that does make sense. However with different durations, when the shorter duration one ends, it does not move from the current position. It jumps seemingly to the position that an object would be moving in the background. As an example, say SKAction 1 is 10 frames and SKAction 2 is 5 frames. It will move to -50 for the first five frames and then I believe it will jump to 50 and move 50 frames more to get to 100. Which is very strange behavior from my understanding and doesn't align with the idea that it animates from the current position.

Comment: I imagine this is because its location is calculated at the moment the `SKAction`s are defined. With your example for example. `SKAction` 1 locations = 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100, `SKAction` 2 locations = -20,-40,-60,-80,-100. So frame 1, x is set to 10 for `SKAction` 1, then immediately set to -20 for `SKAction` 2, then the node is rendered. frame 2, x is set to 20, then immediately set to -40, then the node is rendered...  frame 5 x is set to 50, then immediately set to -100 (`SKAction` 2 completes), frame 6, x is set to 60 by `SKAction` 1.

Comment: That makes so much sense! Thank you very much Craig!!